# How do I access a python http server from a remote connection?

Tags: python, http, networking

I'm trying out the command python http.server from the command line, and am trying to access the server. I can access easily from localhost, but whenever I try to use a remote connection, I am unable to connect.

I've tried different ports, and it doesn't look like my firewall is blocking any connections.

From the command line, I run

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

which returns

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

However, I can only connect to the server from localhost.

```
sudo iptables -S
```

returns the following:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I expect to be able to connect from a remote host with the url http://10.247.30.125:8000 (my ip address), but I am unable to do so. The same url works fine on localhost.

Comment: It's likely you need to port forward. You can also want to google `ngrok`

Comment: I think this is a network configuration question, not a programming question.  "0.0.0.0" means it is listening on all available interfaces.  If you can't reach it, it's because none of your interfaces receives traffic for the address you're trying to use.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what was going on. Did some reading about IP and NAT, and noticed that any ip address beginning with a 10 is reserved for private ip addresses. So, trying to connect to 10.247.30.125:8000 from anywhere other than my own network (so while not connected to my wifi) doesn't work. To be able to connect from an external network, I would need to set up port forwarding (like Reedinationer  suggested), and I would need to use my router's public IP address rather than my computer's private IP address. I would set up a port forward from my router to direct external traffic to my computer, which would allow me to connect to my personal computer from an external network.

Thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 0):

port is missing from the url try this url it should work "http://10.247.30.125:8000"

Comment: good point, that's what I actually tried I just made a typo in the post. I have the same error with "http://10.247.30.125:8000". I edited the post to reflect this.